# WordPress customizer get control

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, api

Is it possible to get a control arguments (title, transport, ...) dynamically when the control value changes?

For example: When we change **Site Title** control, we can get its argument.

```
  api.bind( 'change', function( preset ) {
    console.log( this.control() )
  } );
```

Consider that it should be dynamic for all settings not a specific setting. I know how to get the arguments for a specific setting.